# Set Divider height in TwoWayView Android Library

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm using http://lucasr.org/2013/02/21/introducing-twowayview/ Library for Horizontal Scroll View.

I need to set divider height between the items.

```
<org.lucasr.twowayview.TwoWayView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/scroller_attached_images"
            style="@style/TwoWayView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/editMessage"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" 
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"/>
```

This doesnt work. Can anyone please help me ?

Regards,
Siva

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this is too late now, but you can do this in code using setItemMargin:

```
TwoWayView listView = (TwoWayView) findViewById(R.id.scroller_attached_images);
listView.setItemMargin(10);
```

Comment: do you know how to set the divider color?

Answer (score 0):

From the sample project:

```
final Drawable divider = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.divider);
mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(divider));
```

Where drawables/divider.xml is:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#cccccc"/>
    <size android:width="2dp"
          android:height="2dp" />

</shape>
```